# How to configure JS snippets on VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use VS code to write JS code. On the version 1.0, it was working very well me for. After the upgrade to version 1.1, what is happening is that when I write code, intellisense triggers but the snippets are not the first option.

I.e: while I am writting func... intellinc triggers and suggest me "function" but not as an snippets but as a variable name or similar I guess.

On the Pic below you can see how it looks on my screen:

[image: Here you can see what is happening]

How can I fix it so it works again with the snippets as default option?

Note: the same happens with all regular commands such as if, log, for, etc...

Answer (score 4):

1. Press Ctrl+Shift+P
2. Type "settings" and select either user or workspace settings (depending on where you want the config to be saved)
3. Add the following config variable: `"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"`

This should do what you want, to an extent.  However I have not been able to get VSCode to actually select the snippets by default, even with this setting.  Instead it selects a matching function or variable name, scrolling down the suggestions and leaving the snippets at the top.

**Edit:**

You can also specify `"editor.snippetSuggestions": "inline"`, which seems to make more sense in terms of where the snippets are placed.  I still have the same problem with the wrong item being selected by default, however.